# Mapcalc with r.buffer layer GRASS GIS?

Tags: raster, grass-gis, buffer

I am patching a few rasters together. For my first raster I would like to create a buffer around it and exclude data from the next raster when patching. I need to interpolate between the first two rasters, because this area in the second raster is suspicious.

I created a buffer layer like:

```
r.buffer --overwrite input=raster1 output=raster1_buffers distances=x1,x2,x3,x4
```

I then use mapcalc to create a new raster which has null values within the buffer and raster2's values outside it.

```
r.mapcalc "raster3 = if(raster1_buffers<x1, null(), raster2)"
```

This returns all -nan values. However, if I swap the position of null() and raster2, mapcalc will return a raster with raster2's values within the buffer zone and nan outside.

Can someone shed some light on this problem?

Comment: It's not clear from your question if you want to **exclude** the 2nd raster or to **interpolate** where the 1st and 2nd overlap. Please clarify.

Comment: @Micha Sorry for the confusion. I want to exclude the area = raster1 + 100m buffer from raster2, then interpolate the two rasters. Basically, raster2 covers all the area that raster1 does, but they don't line up identically at their boarders and raster1 is better for the area it covers. So, I want to interpolate between the two over the 100m buffer (or iterate this process over a few buffer distances).

Comment: I guess the "x1,x2,x3" above are numbers?? What are the values contained in raster1. So in your r.mapcalc expression, if raster1 is always lower than x1, then it will return null() everywhere. Perhaps if you post the results of ``r.info raster1`` and ``r.info raster2`` and ``g.region -p`` it will be easier to understand. An image would also help...

Comment: @Micha Yes, I guess that is unclear. "x1,x2,x3" are distances I want to use with a raster buffer (`raster1_buffers`) in order to replace cells within a buffer of one of those distances with nulls in `raster2`. I thought from the documentation that `r.buffer` returned a raster of distances, but I don't think I know exactly whats going on there. However, if I prepend an `@` to the input in `mapcalc`, then the category labels are accessed, instead of the values, which are "x1,x2,x3". This accomplishes what I was attempting to do, but I still don't know why my early method didn't work.